# apply discount and exempt tax calculation for Canada

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tax

The question was asked previously but there was not any proper answer. The problem is I am developing a POS application for a Canadian client. I am stuck in a tax calculation and could not be able to find a solution. So here is my scenario, I have 2 items lets say item 1 = $10 and item 2 = $2. The item 2 is tax exempted means the taxes (13%) will not be apply on item 2 but before applying tax. I need to apply discount for example of $5. So how to apply discount on my total bill and calculate the total tax.

I NEED A TAX AMOUNT AFTER DISCOUNT . THE TAX IS 13%.

Item 1 is $10
item 2 is $2 (Tax Exempt)

Subtotal is $12
Discount is $5
Tax  will be  ?

Comment: If you can use the discount to get item 2 for free then you can apply the remaining $3 discount towards item 1 and then calculate the amount with tax afterwards so it would be 7 * 1.13 IMO but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: First of all you should also share what you've implemented so far. In addition, some details are missing here. Do the 10$ already contain the 13%? Do the taxes have to be applied afterwards? Do you also have all the prices available split into with / without taxes?
Usually you would just calculate every item on it's own (start without taxes, reduce per item by discount amount (% or total) then calculate taxes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Sort the items by price, most expensive first.
2. Apply the discount to the items in the sorted list until no discount is left.
3. Sum the prices of that list to get the discounted subtotal.
4. Sum the prices of the taxable items in that list to get the taxable amount.
5. Apply the tax to the taxable amount, and add it to the subtotal to get the total.

```js
const ITEMS = [
  { price: 2.00, taxExempt: true },
  { price: 10.00, taxExempt: false },
  { price: 8.25, taxExempt: false },
]
const DISCOUNT = 12
const TAX = 0.13

const applyDiscount = (items, discount) => {
  // 1️⃣ sort by price, most expensive to least
  items = items.slice().sort((a,b) => b.price - a.price)

  // 2️⃣
  return items.map(item => {
    let price = item.price
    const itemDiscount = Math.min(price, discount) 
    if (itemDiscount > 0) {
      price -= itemDiscount
      discount -= itemDiscount
    }
    return { ...item, price, origPrice: item.price, itemDiscount }
  })
}

const itemsWithDiscount = applyDiscount(ITEMS, DISCOUNT)
const sumPrices = arr => arr.map(x => x.price).reduce((p,c) => p + c, 0)
const subtotal = sumPrices(itemsWithDiscount) // 3️⃣
const taxableAmt = sumPrices(itemsWithDiscount.filter(x => !x.taxExempt)) // 4️⃣
const total = subtotal + (taxableAmt * TAX) // 5️⃣

console.log('items after discount', itemsWithDiscount)
console.log('subtotal: $' + subtotal.toFixed(2) + ' (taxable: $' + taxableAmt.toFixed(2) + ')')
console.log('tax: $' + (taxableAmt * TAX).toFixed(2) + ' (' + (TAX * 100) + '%)')
console.log('total: $' + total.toFixed(2))
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. but i am still confuse about sorting . If we deduct discount without sorting by checking the totals to avoid negative just like you did using Math.min will it make any effect?

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about sorting much at first because I usually think of all cart items being taxable. And applying the discount to the most expensive items first would minimize the spread of the discount (how many items the discount is applied to).

Comment: However, the order in which the discount is applied could change the total in a cart that has both taxable and tax-exempt items. Let's assume all items have the same price. Applying the discount to the tax-exempt items first costs the buyer more because the taxable amount would be higher. On the other hand, applying the discount to the taxable items first costs less as the taxable amount would be lower. Comment out the sorting in my answer to see a demonstration of *not sorting* (notice how the total changes).